# Find a word in a string in Eng and in a string of Unicode (no space between each word)

Tags: vb.net

(VB.NET, .NET 3.5)

I'm trying to write a function to find a word in a string in the this format : "ThisissometextthatIneedtofindandthisisthetext. This is another text."

It's read as  " This is some text that I need to find and this is the text. This is another text." but there is no space between each word. I want to get the word "text" or any word in that string. Can you help me with this function with a code sample ?

And I think that this method can be implemented with a string of Unicode also because in a sentence of Unicode it contains one or few, sometimes zero spaces between each word.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See String.IndexOf(). It does exactly what you want.

Actually, after trying to find it in the help file, I've reconsidered my response to your question in the comments. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) for examples and documentation. (Finding it, as simple as it should have been, wasn't so simple. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would look up articles on spell checkers. [This](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) is a decent one. I would expect the two problems have very similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To test if a substring exist in a string or unicode, you could use:

```
exists = InStr"ThisissometextthatIneedtofindandthisisthetext. This is another text.", "text") <> 0
```